# WordPress cannot show custom post type on single.php page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a WordPress custom post type called `products`. In my theme’s `function.php` file I wrote the codes (please see the codes below). In the WordPress admin, I can see a new menu called `Products`. I even created a new product, wrote its title and content and saved.

Everything is fine up to this point. I can even see the new “product” post in the front page.

However, when I click it, the WordPress cannot find it and shows the `404 not found` error page. But with a WordPress normal `post` type it does not happen like that, with a custom post type only it happens like that. I searched a lot in Google and followed theirs instructions, but none of them solved my problem.

[image]

Please help. Below is my code:

```html
<?php
add_action('init', 'product_register');
function product_register() {
 $labels = array(
  'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'menu_name'          => _x( 'Products', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Product', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'product', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'new_item'           => __( 'New Product', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'view_item'          => __( 'View Product', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'all_items'          => __( 'All Products', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Products:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'not_found'          => __( 'No products found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
 );

 $args = array(
  'labels'             => $labels,
  'public'             => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui'            => true,
  'show_in_menu'       => true,
  'query_var'          => true,
  'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'product' ),
  'capability_type'    => 'post',
  'has_archive'        => true,
  'hierarchical'       => false,
  'menu_position'      => null,
  'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
 );
 
    register_post_type( 'product' , $args );
 flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
 if ( ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || is_feed() )
 $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product' ) );

 return $query;
}
?>
```

My code is mostly based on help from [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: do you already make file `single-product.php` in template directory?

Comment: Remove `flush_rewrite_rules();`, it is a really really expensive functions which should only be run once on either theme activation or plugin activation. After you have remove that, flush your permalinks manually

Comment: Also, this line `if ( ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || is_feed() )` should be `if ( ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) || $query->is_feed() )`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. Now my custom post type is working.

My mistake was that I was including the custom post type source code file called `products.php` into the `functions.php` file using the condition:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
      include_once('products.php'); 
}
```

Then, by chance, I removed the condition and simply used:

```
include_once('products.php');
```

And now it is working fine. Thanks everyone for your tips and helps. They were very helpful to me.